# Emacs update-file-autoloads failing

Tags: emacs

I'm trying to setup emacs to be my GO IDE by following this [tutorial](http://honnef.co/posts/2013/03/writing_go_in_emacs/) with this [code](https://github.com/dominikh/go-mode.el) .  I'm running into problems when I have to have emacs generate a file

> From within Emacs, run M-x update-file-autoloads, point it at the go-mode.el file and tell it to generate a go-mode-load.el file.

I get this error when I enter the path of the file (location `~/.emacs.d/go-mode/go-mode.el`)

```
Opening output file: no such file or directory, /build/buildd/emacs23-23.3+1/debian/build-x/lisp/loaddefs.el
```

I did a `locate` on this file and see I do have it but not at the path specified path above

```
$ locate loaddefs.el
/usr/share/emacs/23.3/lisp/loaddefs.el
...
```

If I had to guess I would say some kind of path problem.  Do I have to set a path variable somewhere?

I installed emacs through `apt-get install emacs23`

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04

Thanks

**EDIT**

The process I'm doing to get the error.

1. `M-x update-file-autoloads` Enter
2. `Update autoloads for file:` ~/.emacs.d/go-mode/go-mode.el Enter

`Opening output file: no such file or directory, /build/buildd/emacs23-23.3+1/debian/build-x/lisp/loaddefs.el`

Comment: How are you calling update-file-autoloads?  It looks like you are trying to write the autoloads to the file in /build/....  What you need to do is write a new autoload file, not update or overwrite an existing one.  When I run M-x update-file-autoloads and point it at a file, it asks me where I want to write the result.  Does that not happen for you?

Comment: No I don't get asked to write a result. just the `Update autoloads for file:` prompt then the error

Comment: Is there a local definition of `generated-autoload-file' in go-mode.el?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and finally got it working. Open your scratch buffer (or any other empty file) and type in the following two lines

```
(setq generated-autoload-file "~/.emacs.d/go-mode/go-mode-load.el")
(update-file-autoloads "~/.emacs.d/go-mode/go-mode.el")
```

Then evaluate both lines by putting the cursor at then of each line and type in `C-x C-e` to evaluate the line before the cursor. Do this for both lines. Then make sure to open `go-mode-load.el` and save the buffer - apparently emacs does not do this by default.

Once you've done this you can continue to follow the instructions at http://www.honnef.co/posts/2013/03/writing_go_in_emacs/

Disclaimer: I am sure there is a better way to do this and lisp experts will shriek at my answer. I have no clue about lisp and how to use lisp in emacs. I just did an informed guess :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just recently hit this while attempting to get go-mode.el set up on my raspberry pi. Luckily, I had already generated a go-mode-load.el file successfully on my Mac and was able to take a look at that.

In there I saw this comment:

```
;; To update this file, evaluate the following form
;;   (let ((generated-autoload-file buffer-file-name)) (update-file-autoloads "go-mode.el"))
```

So I `cd`'ed into the directory where I had downloaded `go-mode.el`, then `touch`ed a new file called `go-mode-load.el`, opened it up in emacs, pasted in that line of code, evaluated it with `C-x C-e` and it worked like a charm.

**EDIT**

Wasn't able to get the generated file working until I added these lines to the end. As of writing this I haven't taken the time to figure out why they are needed but adding them fixed the problem:

```
(provide 'go-mode-load)
;; Local Variables:
;; version-control: never
;; no-byte-compile: t
;; no-update-autoloads: t
;; coding: utf-8
;; End:
;;; go-mode-load.el ends here
```

Answer (score 1):

(Not an answer, but needs formatting)
Is there a local definition of `generated-autoload-file' in go-mode.el?  If so, it will write there, so you need to remove that line.

---

;; update-file-autoloads docs

update-file-autoloads is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
`autoload.el'.

(update-file-autoloads FILE &optional SAVE-AFTER OUTFILE)

Update the autoloads for FILE.
If prefix arg SAVE-AFTER is non-nil, save the buffer too.

If FILE binds `generated-autoload-file' as a file-local variable,
autoloads are written into that file.  Otherwise, the autoloads
file is determined by OUTFILE.  If called interactively, prompt
for OUTFILE; if called from Lisp with OUTFILE nil, use the
existing value of`generated-autoload-file'.

Return FILE if there was no autoload cookie in it, else nil.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the actual installation instructions from the [go-mode-el GitHub webpage](https://github.com/dominikh/go-mode.el). It looks like there have been some changes which are not reflected in the tutorial.

Just try to either use ELPA or follow the manual instructions:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/place/where/you/put/it/")
(require 'go-mode-autoloads)
```